# Back to back Small MP3 files Playing In Android

Tags: android, mp3

I want to play back to back mp3 files(of half sec) in my android application.I am able to do that on emulator but on mobile phone they all are overlapping with each other.
I have used OnCompletionListerner and stopped the Mediaplayer.
Following  is my code for one mp3 file:

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a10);
mPlayer.start();
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
@Override
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mPlayer.stop();
 }
});
```

Can anybody suggest any method to stop the overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

Try following example :

```
MediaPlayer mp1, mp2;
Timer timer;

// Create two different instances of mediaplayer
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a1);        
mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a2);

// Create the timertask 
timer = new Timer("mytimer");
timer.schedule(timertask1, 1000);
```

**onCompletionListeners:**

```
// Completion listener for Audio file 1. 
    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer cim) {
            //On completion of first audio, release the resources of mediaplayer
            mp1.release();
            mp1 = null;// free up memory
            // Start the timertask of 2nd audio file  
            timer = new Timer("mytimer");
            timer.schedule(timertask2, 1000);
        }
    });

    mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer cim) {
           //On completion of 2nd audio, release the resources of mediaplayer
            mp2.release();
            mp2 = null;
            // Start the timertask of 1st audio file or nxt audio file if you want to              play file or simplly you can stop here.
            timer = new Timer("mytimer");
            timer.schedule(timertask1, 1000);
        }
    });
```

**Timer tasks:**

```
  private TimerTask timertask1 = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
           mp1.start();
    }
  };

  private TimerTask timertask2 = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
           mp2.start();
    }
  };
```

**Note:**
Example is given considering two audio files only, hence two specific onCompletionlisteners and timertasks. However I would suggest you to use generalised code for creating the mediaplayer instance, onCompletionlistener and timertask.